# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function atp_variable() on null

Tags: php

hello i have the next error in an admin option and the line of code is the next one. can you please help me ?

[11-Sep-2021 12:02:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function atp_variable() on null in /var/www/vhosts/*/theme-options.php:858
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/insect.gr/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): atp_options()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/insect.gr/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/insect.gr/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/insect.gr/httpdocs/wp-settings.php(578): do_action()
#4 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1291): require('/var/www/vhosts...')
#5 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1212): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#6 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(23): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#7 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/ve in /var/www/vhosts/*/theme-options.php on line 858

```
        $iva_of_options[] = array(
        'name'    => 'Select Slider Type',
        'desc'    => 'Select which slider you want to use for the Frontpage of the theme.',
        'id'      => $shortname . '_slider',
        'std'     => 'flexslider',
        'class'   => 'select300',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'options' => $atp_theme->atp_variable( 'slider_type' ),
    );
```

the whole code is here codeshare.io/zyXYA7

Comment: What is `$atp_theme`, did you declare it somewhere. You get the error because you try to call a method, but the variable is not a object, it doesn't seem like it was set at all

Comment: in the first of line code i have global $iva_of_options, $shortname, $atp_theme; that you mean ?

Comment: could you show the whole function? it seems like the variable doesn't contain the class instance, so naturally it will not have any methods you can call. The code you added to the question, which is off topic if I'm not mistaken, is not enough to help you with the problem.

Comment: my all code is here https://codeshare.io/zyXYA7

Comment: i have in other php file the $atp_theme = new ATP_theme(); that you mean ?

Comment: Based on the code from the link I say try added that line, seems like that is what's missing

Comment: this line $atp_theme = new ATP_theme(); ?? before or after global ?

Comment: After the global, but you can omit the global $atp_theme if you add the $atp_theme = new ATP_theme(), as it doesn't seem like there is a $atp_theme in the global scope anyway.

Comment: i did it many erros i have i other php the $atp_theme = new ATP_theme(); and in that i have  global $iva_of_options, $shortname, $atp_theme;

Comment: Then try the usual debugging process, disable all plugins, one by one, see if that helps. Next, if that didn't, try a fresh WP install and install the theme on that, if the problem still persists then it's a problem with the theme, so you can contact the theme developer or try a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The error message in your question appears to have been thrown from WP CLI. Based on your other comments the problem is that your theme is not properly declaring a global variable.

Somewhere in your code you have this declared outside a function:

```
$atp_theme = new ATP_theme();
```

Then in other parts of your code you have:

```
global $atp_theme;
```

When using WordPress via the browser, variables declared outside a function, like `$atp_theme` in that first line, are global. So you can access them by using `global`, like in the second line.

The problem is that when using WP CLI, variables declared outside a function are not automatically global. Therefore `global $atp_theme` is undefined.

To solve this you need to explicitly declare the variable as global when defining it, like this:

```
global $atp_theme;

$atp_theme = new ATP_theme();
```

Or this would also work:

```
$GLOBALS['atp_theme'] = new ATP_theme();
```

Comment: maybe the problem is i have 2 $atp_theme in diferent php files one is $atp_theme = new ATP_theme_pest(); and  $atp_theme = new ATP_theme(); maybe that confict ?

Comment: Only if they’re both declared as global. But even then the only reason either would be null is because if the issue I described. A conflict would result in a different error. But look, if you didn’t develop this theme yourself you need to speak to the author.

Comment: so i have already in functions.php $atp_theme = new ATP_Theme(); and when i add it to declare to the theme-options.php it shows up many errors ???

Comment: I never said to do that in my answer. Please read my answer. I have nothing to add.

Comment: i change the declaration with $GLOBALS['atp_theme'] = new ATP_theme(); or global $atp_theme;

$atp_theme = new ATP_theme(); but the error is still there on null